# Pass Vuex data from API to table

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

So, I have a Bootstrap-Vue table in my HTML, and I want to pass a recipe name to my field.

I want to load the data in `recipeItems: []` and pass it to my table. But I keep getting null Id as error response.

```
...mapState({
    recipeName: (state) => state.recipe.name,
    recipeId: (state) => state.recipe.id
})

...mapActions({ 
fetchRecipe: "recipe/fetch"
      setId: "recipe/setId"
 })

mounted() {
   this.setId(this.recipeItems);
    this.fetchRecipe().then(() => {
      this.recipeItems = this.recipeName
      })
}
```

```js
setId({ commit }, id) {
    commit(SET_ID, id);
},
fetch({ commit, state }) {
    return api.recipes.get(state.id).then(({ data }) => {
        commit(SET_NAME, data.name);
```

```js
[SET_NAME](state, name) {
    state.name = name;
},
[SET_ID](state, id) {
      state.id = id;
    },
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: i got this error `GET http://localhost:8001/recipes/null 422` but I figured out I had to add
`this.setId();` , but it's still not working because I need to pass params in this.setId, I do not know what to pass.

Comment: I edited post with code

Comment: You need to import `setId`

Comment: It's in my mapActions `setId: "recipe/setId"`

Comment: Could you add `SET_ID` to your post?

Comment: I've edited, i keep getting ```{"recipe_id":["invalid"]}``` in my web panel.

Comment: The ID is `null`, so at some point in the process it isn't going through as you'd expect. You need to debug and find out where it stops working, isolate which function/method is the issue